# STIntersects with spatial index error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

SO I am trying to get a count of taxi points per census block using STIntersects and the count function. I created a spatial index for the points to only query the SF Bay Area When I run my query I get this error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @POLY GEOMETRY = (SELECT GEOM FROM BayArea_Counties_PH)  
SELECT COUNT(geom) as pct 
FROM DF_Testing1 with (index(BA_Points_Index))
WHERE @POLY.STIntersects(Geom)=1
group by 
Id
```

I hope to group by ID or something so that I can visualize intensity per block on a map. Any ideas?

Comment: Trying to understand you query; what is the purpose of DF_Testing1?  Reason I ask is that the table is not returning any values, joined to other tables, or predicated.  Also, regarding your error, you are trying to set multiple values into a scalar variable. Can you clarify?

Comment: @MikeZalansky So DF_Testing1 is a table of points of Drop offs of Taxi Cabs. I created a Geometry column for it and created a spatial index to only index SF Bay Area counties points. How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as stated by another poster) is that you're trying to assign multiple values to a scalar when you declare @POLY. This could do what you want, however, with fewer steps:

```
SELECT b.id, t.id, COUNT(geom) as pct 
FROM DF_Testing1 as [t] with (index(BA_Points_Index))
join BayArea_Counties_PH as [b]
   on b.Geom.STIntersects(t.Geom) = 1
group by b.Id, t.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe here is the issue:

```
DECLARE @POLY GEOMETRY = (SELECT GEOM FROM BayArea_Counties_PH)
```

How many records do you have in BayArea_Counties_PH? It has to be one  to assign GEOM to the variable correctly. You should add a correct `WHERE` clause for that line to work if you have multiple records.